# Google sitemap access error, something to do with .htaccess redirect from http://www. to http://

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, sitemap, mod-rewrite

I recently updated the `.htaccess` of my site to redirect from `http://www.` to `http://`.

It all works fine but now I've made some changes to my site and uploaded a new `sitemap.xml` to Google Search Console (formerly Google Webmaster Tools). I'm getting the following message:

> "We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.
>   **General HTTP error: Domain name not found**"

I made the sitemap using `xml-sitemaps.com`, any idea how I might resolve this?

---

The domain is: `http://example.com`

The sitemap is: `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`

The `.htaccess` is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: just been having a play around with it, if i remove the .htaccess file from the server it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you should check is your [preferred domain](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231) in Google Webmaster Tools.  If you've told Google to prefer `www.lightandspace.co.uk` over just `lightandspace.co.uk`, but you now have the former redirecting to the latter, that might well cause some crawling issues.

More generally, it seems that the ["General HTTP error: Domain name not found"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22General+HTTP+error%3A+Domain+name+not+found%22) error is typically caused by DNS issues.  However, both of your hostnames resolve just fine for me, even via [Google's public DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), so if that's the problem then I'm unable to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

(Old question, but...)

> ```
> rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://lightandspace.co.uk$1 [r=301,nc]
> ```

This directive is invalid in a `.htaccess` (or *directory*) context and will certainly result in a DNS error if requesting the www subdomain. (This affects all URLs, except the document root, not just the `/sitemap.xml` URL. So I'm not sure what "It all works fine" is referring to specifically?)

Specifically, the *substitution* is missing a slash after the hostname. The `$1` backreference does not contain a slash prefix (as would seem to be expected) because in a `.htaccess` context the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does not contain a slash prefix. (The URL-path that is matched against is less the directory-prefix. The directory-prefix always *ends* with a slash, so the URL-path that is matched never *starts* with a slash. This behaviour is different to when the directive is used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context - in this case the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the full URL-path, which naturally does start with a slash.)

For example, if Google is requesting `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml` then your site will redirect this to `http://example.comsitemap.xml`, which will simply fail to resolve and a "General HTTP error: Domain name not found" error will be reported.

So, in a `.htaccess` context, you need to explicitly include the slash. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note also, the `NC` flag was superfluous here (you are matching *everything*, regardless of case). And you probably need the `L` flag to terminate further processing of your directives (if you have more directives). Regex is *greedy* by default, so `^(.*)$` is the same as `(.*)` - it matches *everything*.

Alternatively, you can use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, which contains the full URL-path, including the slash prefix:

```
RewriteRule .* http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```